# how to copy photos sent to the specified channel to another channel discord

Tags: node.js, discord.js

hello I already did the code I mentioned. but on the console, on the server, it send the photo into the channel more than once, even 30 times in a row how can i fix this ? also i want embedding this but i think attachments not working on embed. here is my code;
edit: i added bulkDelete because if i dont like i said its send million times

```
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.attachments.size > 0) {
    msg.channel.bulkDelete(1)
const channel1 = msg.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === "önemli-duyuru");
const channel2 = msg.guild.channels.find(r => r.name === "⚠│kural");
const files = [channel1.lastMessage.attachments.first()].map(attachment => attachment.proxyURL);
channel2.send(`Bu Fotoğraf ${msg.author} Tarafından Gönderildi.`, {files});
    console.log(files)
  }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When receiving the message, make sure to check whether your bot is the message author, otherwise you'll get stuck in a potentially endless loop:

```js
if (msg.author.id === client.user.id) return
```

`message` events are emitted for every message, including the ones sent by the bot.

Comment: Check https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setImage if you want to add an image to an embed

Comment: it's not working. its says its has to be buffer or string. because files output like this;